# How to manipulate 3D character in Unity being embeded in Flutter using pose detection?

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine

Ok so my project is to manipulate 3D characters in real-time using the users kinematics. For kinematics, i am using Google ML kit pose detection to get the landmarks of every joint. and As flutter does not support any 3D rendering so for that i am embedding a unity app inside a flutter so i can detect values in flutter using the camera and send those landmarks to unity module/app.
i tried using animation rigging in unity but the points are not matched as it should.

so i have integrated flutter and unity and i am also able to transfer the landmarks of joints to unity from flutter. now i have also created a rig for right hand connecting shoulder, elbow and wrist. now when i try to give the values to this rig, its not moving the hand the way the points i am getting.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is orbetter **was** a custom JavaScript flavour-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Are you sure you want to ask something about that language?

Comment: And also note that in the current state your question is to broad/off-topic. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in particular `3. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.